# Caffe snapshot training modem

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network, training-data, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new to Caffe. I'm trying to train a Caffe CNN, the problem after running the training the Caffe model it doesn't appear in thee folder. I can only get the snapshot file.
The CNN I'm trying to do is the example of Lrcn.  here's it's [link](https://github.com/LisaAnne/lisa-caffe-public/tree/lstm_video_deploy/examples/LRCN_activity_recognition) , also the part in trying to train is the CNN because I can't train the lstm without the caffe model.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What do you want to get? Set the snapshop parameter in the solver.prototxt to save a snapshot of the trained model.

Comment: Another question caffemodel that you can find in zoo model are the same (in structure) that snapshot.caffemodel?

Comment: The file extension ".caffemodel" is a snapshot

Comment: Did you find solution? I am looking for same.